# Create AKS Cluster with Application Gateway Ingress Add-on via Bicep Template

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cli, azure-bicep

I was following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-new) to setup AKS with Application Gateway Ingress Controller.

I am wondering what is the equivalent of this Azure CLI Command using Bicep Templates?

```
az aks create -n myCluster -g myResourceGroup --network-plugin azure --enable-managed-identity -a ingress-appgw --appgw-name myApplicationGateway --appgw-subnet-cidr "10.2.0.0/16" --generate-ssh-keys
```

Especially as it seems that the node resource group name can only be configured using ARM/Bicep as the corresponding parameter mentioned in the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-provide-my-own-name-for-the-aks-node-resource-group) seems to have vanished in the current version of the AKS Extension.

Update: The thing i'm mostly uncertain about is how to activate and configure the Add-On "ingress-appgw" via Template.

I saw that in the export of an AKS Cluster provisioned by the above command i get this section:

```
 "addonProfiles": {
                "azurepolicy": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "ingressApplicationGateway": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "config": {
                        "applicationGatewayName": "my-agw",
                        "effectiveApplicationGatewayId": "[parameters('applicationGateways_my_agw_externalid')]",
                        "subnetCIDR": "10.2.0.0/16"
                    }
                }
            }
```

If that is enough to achieve the same job i'm good but i'm not sure if the Azure CLI Command does some extra sorcery on top of that in AKS to make it all work.

Comment: Could you share with us what you have tried so far and what's not working ? You can for sure export a template from the Azure portal if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this template as starter: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/91da267dce8691485d916f7315a3fe6ffcee21aa/quickstarts/microsoft.network/aks-application-gateway-ingress-controller/azuredeploy.json#L1797

It's ARM, but you can easily transform it to Bicep, something like:

```
addonProfiles: {
    {
      ingressApplicationGateway: {
        enabled: true
        config: {
          applicationGatewayId: applicationGateway.id
        }
      }
}
```

Add identity if you use it.